# Finding top level of Hierarchical tree

Tags: oracle, hierarchical-data

I need to find the top level of a hierarchy.. (max level)

Basically I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE HIERARCHY_TREE
(
  ID            NUMBER(38),
  FEEDER        VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  NAME          VARCHAR2(68 BYTE),
  PARENT        NUMBER(38)
)
```

And the scenario is that I may have a **FEEDER** (parent) with N **NAME** (child)... Also I may have as much "brothers" for **NAME**, but all of them with the same **FEEDER**. So for a given **FEEDER**, I have this hierarchy.

```
LEVEL   ID          PARENT          FEEDER          NAME              ELEMENT_ABOVE
1       6589                        ITI02           ITI02
2       12242       6589            ITI02           AE23              ITI02
3       12330       12242           ITI02           KD01              AE23
4       12355       12330           ITI02           LOD44             KD01
4       1583285     12330           ITI02           US821             KD01
5       12796       1583285         ITI02           MBADE1233         US821
6       12792       12796           ITI02           LIIIK911          MBADE1233
6       12792       12796           ITI02           MMQQWWE1234       MBADE1233
5       12879       1583285         ITI02           PE33321           US821
5       13043       1583285         ITI02           TP120120          US821
6       1937994     13043           ITI02           KDKKD102102       MBADE1233
7       10424       1937994         ITI02           QIEI124           KDKKD102102
7       13047       1937994         ITI02           KDII123123        KDKKD102102
```

I am doing this with the following query:

```
SELECT LEVEL lev,
       id,
       PARENT,
       FEEDER,
       t.name,
       PRIOR t.NAME AS element_above,
       FROM HIERARCHY_TREE t
         WHERE FEEDER = :feeder
    CONNECT BY PRIOR t.ID = t.PARENT
            START WITH t.PARENT IS NULL AND t.FEEDER = :feeder
```

This works fine for 99% of existent **feeder**. But for a few one I have an infinite loop and I can't identify the problem... So I have some questions:

- Is this the best way to do it? If not, how to improve it?
- Is there a way to identify possibles infinite-loop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `connect by nocycle PRIOR t.ID = t.PARENT` and `SELECT  CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE as IS_infinite_loop, ...` to detect them

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I don't know exactly if the problem is an infinite loop... I presume so. I'm trying to use the `nocycle` as you said but it's running for more than five minutes... it's kinda the same problem... it keeps running forever and never finishes..

Comment: It may be related to how much data and how deep your structure is. Relational databases CAN do hierarchical queries but it isn't what they were designed for; slow down is almost unavoidable after a few levels.

Comment: I understand @BriteSponge... but there is no escape? No solutions?

Comment: 'Top level' of a hierarchical query, to me, means those records that satisfy the START WITH condition. If that condition (PARENT IS NULL) is sufficient then cant you just use that without retrieving all the other records ? If you mean those at the bottom, i.e. have no children then you could try qualifying it on CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF but I'm not sure if that will speed things up much.

Comment: 'Top level' is the maximum number of childs - with "daddies"..So I don't think CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF would fit right?